# Test to prove change in data structure over time?

Tags: time-series, structural-change

Hello its my first time here!

I have a data of engine oil with its 18 parameters. We measure them every 1000km. It is being measured 11 times.

At each measurment each of parameters change. 
How I can prove that the actual structure is changing? (I think i has to compare 18 variables over 11 times?)

I was thinking about using ANOVA (or similiar) and making 18 groups with 11 measurments, then comparing those groups. What should I do? It is needed to show some kind of statistic "evidence" to prove that the structure is changing.

Thanks in advance for help!

UPDATE: I actually used now similiarity analysis with Bray-Curtis indices. I wonder if anybody agrees with it? How I could use it for any statistics now?

Comment: What do you mean by "the actual structure is changing"? That, say, the distribution of the parameters at the first measurement $\theta_1$ is different from the distribution of parameters at measurement $\theta_{11}$? That there is some $n$ for which $\{\theta_1, \dots, \theta_{n-1}\}$ follow one distribution and $\{\theta_n, \dots, \theta_{11}\}$ follow a different distribution ([changepoint detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_detection))?

Comment: No no, its not about change point. Its about detecting for example that one of variables (let it be absorption of one of compounds) of oil to change in different way than others. For example growing when others are getting smaller, therefore the actual ratio between them changes. I was thinking about ANOVA or sth like this, because  I may detect differences in SD, that is which variables changes faster or sth. I hope I managed to explain. (well it seems similiar..)

Comment: Do you want to include time-based changes (i.e. look at the 11 data points  per parameter as a time series), or just compare all 18 values at each individual value of t (11 independent comparisons)?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [ARIMA models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive%E2%80%93moving-average_model) for modelling each of your parameters independently.

Since you have multiple predictors [Vector Autoregression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_autoregression) might provide a more descriptive model if you suspect there are relationships between your 18 parameters that you can use for predicting future values of each of the 18 parameters based on the historical values of all of your 18 parameters.

As an example, assume you have a VAR model that uses your 18 parameters at times **(t-2)** and **(t-1)** to predict your 18 parameters at time **t**:

$$
\{y_1, \dots, y_{18}\}_{t-2},\{y_n, \dots, y_{18}\}_{t-1} \rightarrow \{y_n, \dots, y_{18}\}_t
$$

You could then iterate **t** from **t=3...11** to build a succession of VAR models of the predicted parameters at **t**. If the predictions for any of the parameters differed from their observed values at time **t**, you could conclude that there was a structural change in the differing parameters. The number of lags might have to be larger than 2 (and therefore your starting **t > 3**) in order to have a robust enough model to detect a structural change.

The error measure between the predicted and observed values would then be measure of the size of the structural change (i.e. a change not successfully predicted) across all 18 parameters.

Finally, if you use R, the "forecast" package has some very powerful tools for building ARIMA models. The R package "vars" makes it very easy to fit and analyse vector auto-regression models as it produces a list of linear models.

Comment: Am I thinking right that this will detect of lagged correlation? I was looking for a change i structure at this moment, It doesnt seem to work. I create a correlation coefficients matrix and there are linear dependencies in couple of variables. I cannot see how to use VAR in case like this, where i do not expect that changes in one moment in oil will provide change in next moment i another variable. More likely that there will be any change. Please correct me if im wrong.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand "More likely that there will be any change". VAR should find both relationships across your 18 parameters and for different lags. i.e. relationships both between different parameters and across time. I've added an example as my answer wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Yes. I finally understand, thank You. I tried this and it occurs that signal is more less white noise. Only for first lags I can see some differences. I ve been using acf and pacf in R so far. And i received something like this [link](https://www.sendspace.com/file/abwn3x), what do You think? ( I changed data to long format (one variable after another, after that another time series start with same order), then I run acf)

Comment: Sorry, I cannot access the link.